# Portable table/stand for cutting wood or boards?

Tags: tool-selection, tool-identification

I was looking for a portable table to use for cutting wooden pieces and panels. I saw one in a photo of a tool, but even after long google searches I just can't find what to call it or search for. Attached the photo below.

[image: See the table/stand marked in red.]

Comment: A common "Kleenex" term for these (where a brand is often use generically) is a "workmate". Web and retailer searches will know what you mean.

Comment: What will you be cutting, with what kind of frequency and using what kind(s) of saw? There are far superior options to this kind of light-duty folding workbench if you may be doing any kind of heavy work. The type featured can be so poor in the worst cases that you start to stress their joints the first time you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a variety of search terms, but the one set with the best result is "folding clamping work table tool" which appeared to exclude a number of inappropriate responses. There are differing features from one product to the next, although the one shown does appear and can be found at [Worthpoint](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/folding-work-bench-tilt-turn-clamping-1797649904), which appears to be a page for an eBay store.

[image: folding clamping work table tool image]

The link I've posted is nearly worthless, but the search terms show that there are other sources, including Walmart (out of stock), Alibaba and a few other China-based operations.

You may find that the search terms provide you with a different product, better suited to your needs, or may provide for a better source for this item.